# JSON login with symfony and react js returning 401 when credentials are correct

Tags: php, reactjs, symfony

I'm building my application with ReactJS + Symfony for the backend/api. When my login form is submitted, and the correct credentials are correctly inputted, the response from my fetch command is returning 401 (and the user object isn't passed through). On refresh, the user is logged in. I'm not sure what I'm missing here as I've followed the Symfony documentation for JSON login [(as outlined here)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#json-login)

My reactJS login page:

```
//Import react...
import React from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function Login() {

    function handleLogin(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        const email = e.target.loginemail;
        const password = e.target.loginpassword;

        if(!email.value.replace(/\s/g, '').length || !password.value.replace(/\s/g, '').length)
        {
            !email.value.replace(/\s/g, '').length ? email.classList.add('is-invalid') : "";
            !password.value.replace(/\s/g, '').length ? password.classList.add('is-invalid') : "";
            
            email.classList.contains("is-invalid") ? email.nextSibling.innerHTML = "This field is required" : "";
            password.classList.contains("is-invalid") ? password.nextSibling.innerHTML = "This field is required" : "";

            return;
        }
    
        fetch('/api/login', {
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "security" : {
                    "credentials" : {
                        email: e.target.loginemail.value,
                        password : e.target.loginpassword.value
                    }
                },
            }),
        })
        .then(response => {
            response.json().then((data) => {
                if(data.user){
                    console.log(data)
                }
            });
        });
    }
    
    function checkLogin(){
        const navigate = useNavigate();
    
        fetch('/api/check-status')
        .then(response => {
            response.json().then((data) => {
                if(data.loggedIn){
                    console.log(data);
                    // navigate("")
                }
            });
        });
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', checkLogin());

    return(
        <>
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row justify-content-center">
                <div className="col-lg-4">
                    <div className="card p-2">
                        <h1 className="mb-3">Log in</h1>
                        <form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
                            <div className="mb-2">
                                <label htmlFor="loginemail" className="form-label">Email</label>
                                <input type="email" className="form-control" id="loginemail" placeholder="someemail@address.com" />
                                <div className="feedback invalid-feedback"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="mb-3">
                                <label htmlFor="loginpassword" className="form-label">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" className="form-control" id="loginpassword" placeholder="Shhh its a secret" />
                                <div className="feedback invalid-feedback"></div>
                            </div>
                            <button className="btn btn-primary w-100 mb-2" type="submit">Sign in</button>
                            <span>Don't have an account? <a href="/register">Sign up now</a></span>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </>
    )
};

export default Login;
```

My controller for the `api/login`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Attribute\CurrentUser;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class ApiLoginController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/api/login', name: 'api_login', methods: 'POST')]
    public function index(#[CurrentUser] ?User $user, Request $request): Response
    {
        if (null === $user) {
            return $this->json([
                'message' => 'Wrong credentials',
            ], Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

        return $this->json([
            'user'  => $user->getUserIdentifier(),
            'token' => $token,
            'referrer' => $request->headers->get('referer')
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/api/logout', name: 'api_logout')]
    public function logout(): Response
    {
        throw new \Exception('Don\'t forget to activate logout in security.yaml');
    }

    #[Route('/api/check-status', name: 'api_status')]
    public function status(): Response
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();

        if(null === $user)
        {
            return $this->json([
                'loggedIn' => false
            ]);
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->json([
                'loggedIn' => true,
                'username' => $user->getUserIdentifier()
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

What is causing the return to not notice the login, even though it would actually log in (after page refresh)? Why does this happen exactly?

Comment: Do you receive a message from the request? Have you managed to debug your problem?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69809320/symfony-currentuser-attribute-returns-null) can help.

Comment: You can try `$user = $this->getUser();` instead of the annotated parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Given the provided function:

```php
#[Route('/api/login', name: 'api_login', methods: 'POST')]
    public function index(#[CurrentUser] ?User $user, Request $request): Response
    {
        if (null === $user) {
            return $this->json([
                'message' => 'Wrong credentials',
            ], Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

        return $this->json([
            'user'  => $user->getUserIdentifier(),
            'token' => $token,
            'referrer' => $request->headers->get('referer')
        ]);
    }
```

And given the provided documentation's function:

```
// ...
+ use App\Entity\User;
+ use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Attribute\CurrentUser;

  class ApiLoginController extends AbstractController
  {
      #[Route('/api/login', name: 'api_login')]
-     public function index(): Response
+     public function index(#[CurrentUser] ?User $user): Response
      {
+         if (null === $user) {
+             return $this->json([
+                 'message' => 'missing credentials',
+             ], Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
+         }
+
+         $token = ...; // somehow create an API token for $user
+
          return $this->json([
-             'message' => 'Welcome to your new controller!',
-             'path' => 'src/Controller/ApiLoginController.php',
+             'user'  => $user->getUserIdentifier(),
+             'token' => $token,
          ]);
      }
  }
```

I can say, it appears that an "Undefined Variable Error" has occurred in your Symfony API. To resolve this issue, you need to define and assign a value to the variable "$token" prior to the call that uses it in the return statement.

To assist with this, you may consider following this helpful guide on setting up JWT authentication with Symfony [How to setup JWT authentication with Symfony](https://medium.com/@edouard.courty/how-to-enable-jwt-authentication-with-symfony-83a05ab2592f) , which can aid in defining and assigning the variable correctly. Alternatively, if you do not require the token, you may simply remove the "$token" variable altogether.